# phpMyAdmin mySql mamp - table does not open

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have a mysql table with just 4 columns and it contains just a bit more than 4800 records. My problem is that I can't open the table to see the content in phpmyadmin. When I try, i have no errors but the page becomes blank. I still have the phpmyadmin column menu on the left. The strange thing is when I try to export the data I can export all the records properly...

By the way I am using MAMP.

Hope someone can help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pretty big fan of [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) on OS X rather than using phpmyadmin. Maybe give that a try.